# Java EE Schedule is looping (not stopping when dayOfWeek is set to another then today) (is it bug)?

Tags: java, loops, jakarta-ee, schedule

everyone. I'm new to here (stackoverflow). I'm having problems with implementing the Schedule in Java EE. My code:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)

public class MySchedule {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)    
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek = "Sun", hour = "1", minute = "0", second = "0" )    
    public void sendMailWithAttachments()
    {
        // do some manipulation
    }
```

The problem is that this method is invoking without stopping when I deploy it. It works OK only when dayOfWeek is set to todays day. If today is Sunday and dayOfWeek = "Sun" it works ok, but when I try to change it to Mon or other days and redeploy the looping occurs.
I'm using glassfish 3.1.2.2

Comment: What do you mean by _looping occurs_? What part of the code is looping? How do you detect this?

Comment: The method sendMailWithAttachments() is calling many times. I have tried to set the persistent = false, but it did not help.

Comment: Hello, @Keppil. In // do some manipulation part I'm just printing out message that this method was called.